# Как получить часть HTML кода другой страницы на том же домене с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: xml, домен, javascript, html

Как получить часть HTML кода другой страницы на том же домене с помощью JavaScript?

Comment: Делаем аякс запрос, парсим получный результат, т.е. отсеиваем регуляркой нужную нам часть страницы - profit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [jquery load()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_HTML-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

```
$('#result').load('your_page.html #Your_container_with_html');
```

Comment: тут кусок страницы нужен поэтому не катит :)

Comment: чего не катит, указывается селектор блока, весь хтмл которого загрузится в резалт

Comment: Прошу прощения, не увидел селектор...(подсветка непривычная :))

Comment: Спасибо, ребят)Помогло

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get('url.html',function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

Вместо алерта - обрабатываем полученную страницу, доставая необходимую ЧАСТь.