# Подмена участков кода страницы из HTML файла

Tags: javascript

Необходимо сделать подмену кода на странице (из HTML файла). Примерно все это изображено на схеме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать это через .innerHTML не очень удобно, так как код очень большой и его нужно постоянно редактировать. Вариант замены из HTML файла будет значительно удобнее, впрочем, если существуют более простые варианты, с удовольствием хотел бы о них узнать. Так же, может быть несколько вариантов отображения для одного элемента. Упрощенный пример кода:

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>Текст</p>
</div>

<ul class="select-list">
    <li><a href="#">Вариант 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Вариант 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Вариант 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

При нажатии на один из пунктов, берем код из привязанного к этому пункту файла "site.com/code1.html" и делаем замену. Так же, было бы очень хорошо, если вариант выбора будет запоминаться браузером и при переходе по страницам оставлять выбранный вариант.

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки.

Comment: джаваскрипт не может залезть на диск и прочитать файл. для безопасности так сделали. можно только залезть из окна 1 в окно 2 при условии ,что окно 2 открылось из окна 1. по-моему, иннерХТМЛ - единственный вариант

Comment: С небольшой помощью jquery библиотеки можно сделать так, как указано тут. [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/40781/) Оно загрузит ваш html в выбранный блок `$('#result').load('your_page.html #Your_container_with_html');`

Comment: Ок, а что если сделать страницу внутри сайта в которой под разными классами будет находится код? Через GET запрос получить код и вставить в нужное место. Это возможно?

Comment: Если пресловутые HTML-файлы лежат на  сервере, то, возможно, Вам будет достаточно использовать `iframe` и просто изменять значение атрибута `src`.

Comment: Почему именно html формат? Необходимую разметку и содержание можно прописать и в пхп, и подгружать аяксом по клику.

Answer (score 2):

Встраивание готовой html-страницы в другую html-страницу делается с помощью [фреймов](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe). Это единственный способ встраивать полноценный html в другой html.

```
<iframe id="myframe" target="frametarget" src="http://mysite.com/page1.html"></iframe>
```

Навигация в таком фрейме осуществляется путём изменения свойства `src`:

```
$("#myframe").attr("src", "http://mysite.com/page2.html")
```

Или ссылками вида:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/page3.html" target="frametarget">MyLink</a>
```

Однако, сейчас такой подход многими считается устаревшим. Отношение верстальщиков к встраиванию html-страниц целиком в другие страницы с помощью фреймов, примерно такое же, как у программистов к оператору `goto`. Причина негативного отношения связана с тем, что сайты с фреймами плохо индексируются поисковиками, содержимое фреймов сбрасывается при обновлении страницы, возникают проблемы при печати таких страниц и нажатии кнопок "назад"/"вперёд".

В качестве альтернативы можно попробовать:

1. Какие-либо javascript-[шаблонизаторы](https://habrahabr.ru/post/219873/)
2. xslt-трансфомацию ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), [учебник на W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/))
3. Передачу данных в формате JSON

В каждом, из этих трёх случаев, перед тем, как ототображать данные тем или иным способом, их нужно будет получить с сервера. Наиболее простой способ - использование jQuery ajax ([[1]](http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-ajax/), [[2]](http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-ajax/)).

Конечно же, остаётся вариант с серверной генерацией страницы целиком.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать реализацию через фрейм.